# Elasticsearch : filter on scripted sum of filtered nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, nested

I'm trying to do something with elasticsearch and don't find the answer anywhere.

Got a nested object products :

```
 "products": {
    "include_in_root": true,
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
        "type": "date"
      },
      "type": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "cat4": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "geo": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "baseprice": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "cat2": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "cat3": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "feeltemp": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "cat1": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "qty": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "weather": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "stock": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "brand": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to query them only if type='cartadd' and cat1="test" for example.

Problem, if a query with nested filter :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "products",
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "sum=0;for(obj in _source.products) {sum = sum + 1 }; sum>=1;"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "products.type": "view"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It counts nothing.

If i remove the nested operation :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "sum=0;for(obj in _source.products) {if(obj.type=='cartadd') {sum = sum + obj.price }}; sum>=2;"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works and count objects. But i cannot filter nested objects anymore.

Has you can see, i added an if condition in groovy script, but i can have lot more conditions dynamically added.

Does somebody have an idea of how i can do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `script` filter outside of the `nested` query since it is operating on `products` which is a field of the parent document (not the nested ones):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "sum=0;for(obj in _source.products) {sum = sum + 1 }; sum>=1;"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "products",
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "products.type": "view"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Besides, a good idea would be to add a new field called `nbProducts` in the parent document that would contain the number of products objects. That would allow you to get rid of that script and do a simple query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "nbProducts": {
              "gte": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "products",
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "products.type": "view"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problems are :
> In first solution, it counts all products, but not filtered by type=view
> In the second solution, nbProducts is not dynamic. i need to add lot of other filters.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want to only count the products that match the `products.type=view` condition? That's intrinsic, if you get one nested `products` match, then the product count is necessarily >= 1 since at least one matches. If you have more criteria, you can add them to a `bool/filter` inside your `nested` query.